# Java how to establish connection link between 2 remote PC

Tags: java, sockets, networking

I would like to develop a website for remotely control PC. How can use java to establish a connection link between 2 remote PC. Said I from US 192.168.1.2 IP add connecting to Canada 192.168.1.221 IP add? I was confusing that how 2 different network pc can connect together?

Comment: These IPs won't do, they are local IPs and cannot be reached through the Internet. Before going to the programming part, you should learn how IP works (you can use a telnet/RDP for this before programming)

Comment: If said using same network will it do?

Comment: Ok, long answer. In your LAN your IPs will be 192.168.x.x or 10.x.x.x (there are a few ranges more). If you look for one of these IPs it will be searched in your LAN, not in internet. If you want to connect to a PC through internet you will have to connect the public IP of its LAN, and its router will have to forward your request to the correct PC (that must be configured in the other LAN).

Comment: Got it thanks. Possible that the router will block this kind of request? If not I can anyhow get an IP address and remote control it?